# populating nopcommerce(version 3.70) database

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, nopcommerce, auto-populate

I am doing a BI project about e-commerce website. I have a complete database back-end(SQL Server 2014) for nopCommerce(version 3.70). I need to populate the empty database. Rather than manually place the order in nopCommerce font-end, do I have other methods to populate the database? I know there are relationships among tables and we cannot just simply import csv files to populate a single table.

Are there any source code I can use to automatically import data to nopCommerce back-end? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying

> I have a complete database back-end(SQL Server 2014) for nopCommerce(version 3.70)

Is it from PROD or Just a empty DB?

Best is to get a Whole backup from PROD with Products, Categorises, Customers and Orders. Manually populating is a daunting task and defeat the purpose of BI Project. Because manual data insertion wont be good as real customer data.

Thats my 2 cents.

Source: Ex-NopCommerce developer for 3 years.